# how can iI to pass an instrucction by param in NetLogo?

Tags: netlogo

Hello I have the following function

```
to calc-col [x]
    ask x [set pcolor gray]
end
```

but I want

```
to calc-col [x y]
    ask x y
end
```

is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, though how you'd do it is changing between NetLogo 5.x and 6.x ([which is currently in beta](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/6.0-BETA1/)).

In NetLogo 5.x, you can do this using [tasks](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/programming.html#tasks):

```
to calc-col [ x y ]
  ask x [ run y ]
end
```

You then call this like so: `calc-col some-agent task [ set pcolor grey ]`

In NetLogo 6.x, tasks have been replaced by [anonymous procedures](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/6.0-BETA2/docs/programming.html#anonymous-procedures). You run them in the exact same way (with `run` or `run-result`), but you define them using the new `->` syntax:

`calc-col some-agent [ [] -> set pcolor grey ]`